# How to hit / deflect a photon?

Tags: particle-physics, photons

If you were trying to scatter a photon, what would be the best thing to try to fire at? Another photon? An electron? A proton?

Does the energy of the thing I'm firing increase the probability of scattering the photon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Photons are elementary point particles in the [standard model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model) of particle physics. Interactions of elementary particles depend on quantum mechanics, and are studied using quantum field theory.

There are four [fundamental forces](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Forces/funfor.html) through which particles interact, with each other, photons interact mainly with the electromagetic force. "Mainly" because the calculations are done with an expansion in a mathematical series in a perturbation theory.

To scatter a photon with high probability one should choose a charged particle from the table of particles linked  above.

Photon photon scattering is very improbable at low energies, though at high energies the  probability goes up.

These are the [lowest order scattering  Feynman diagrams](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/445774/compton-scattering-lowest-order-feyman-diagram) for photon electron scattering.

[image]

In general scattering crossections grow with the energy available for the interaction.

Photons will also scatter from the electric and magnetic fields of atoms and molecules.

Comment: Is a photon more likely to scatter from a proton than the smaller electron?

Comment: for high energy it is complicated by the production of  particles. see this https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/241994/compton-scattering-by-proton/242005